# Custom Firefox profile load in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-chromedriver

I had a code to open browsers with Selenium with google chrome in Windows. It worked perfectly, but now I want to try it with Firefox and this is the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=~/.mozilla/firefox/a0kvymyz.default-release") #Path to your firefox profile
driver= webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()),options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

But when I open it, the log info, cookies,extensions... are not loaded, its a default browser session. Is the syntax correctly? Because this was working in google chrome (Windows). I had to change the syntax of the 3rd and 4th line because I changed from selenium 3 to 4, I'm 50% sure that maybe that is the problem.

Regards, Isaac.

Comment: ~/.mozilla/firefox/a0kvymyz.default-release Try using the full path.

Comment: Without the "user-data-dir=' ? @ArundeepChohan